# How to :not for two attributes in CSS calendar picking

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

If i have table like:

```
<td class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day--not-this-month">
    <time class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day__number">--</time>
</td>

<td class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day--unavailable">
    <time class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day__number">--</time>
</td>

<td class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day">
    <time class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day__number">--</time>
</td>

<td class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day">
    <time class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day__number">--</time>
</td>

<td class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day">
    <time class="search-unit-custom-control-calendar-day__number">--</time>
</td>
```

How can I select available dates, like:

```
`tbody.search-unit-custom-control-calendar__table__page tr td[class*=calendar-day-]:not([class*='unavailable'] && [class*='--not-this-month']))`
```

When I am using this it is not working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to add a second `:not` condition instead of concatenating them with an `&&`.

Like this:

```
tbody.search-unit-custom-control-calendar__table__page tr td[class*=calendar-day]:not([class*='unavailable']):not([class*='--not-this-month'])
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vbn0xrf/)

Comment: it didnt work, i even tried :not([class*='unavailable']), :not([class*='--not-this-month']) this is not working either

Comment: @LaxmiMaddali see if the fiddle helps

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what fiddle is ?? Can you please help

Comment: Your main problem I think is the extra `-` you have here: `td[class*=calendar-day-]`. I think it would make more sense to have it as `td[class*=calendar-day]`

Comment: Click the "see this fiddle" link in my post. Its a demo of my solution

Comment: it is able to find the element with tbody.search-unit-custom-control-calendar__table__page tr td[class*=calendar-day]:not([class*='unavailable']) but selects not-this-month column on calendar, so i want to add not for this.

Comment: I think you are close. Can you try this again (there was an error in the selector before): `tbody.search-unit-custom-control-calendar__table__page tr td[class*="calendar-day"]:not([class*="unavailable"]):not([class*="--not-this-month"])`

Comment: This is selecting not-this-month as well

Answer (score 0):

The css selector is not right, the parent selector `td[class*=calendar-day-]` exclude all `td` that don't has a composed class *(no dash after class name)* so it left out the four last cells. Look at [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/auxcoder/y0gfczq4/).